# Combining Compliment and Substitue Goods

Tags: macroeconomics

Given
1) Perfect substitutes: X and Y
2) Compliments: Z and X
is it possible to generate a utility function that relates them?

X and Z must always be consumed together, and you can substitute Y for X.

Comment: Do you need perfect compliments? If so try U=min{x+y, z}. If you need just some degree of complimentaritt then try      u=(x+y)*z

Comment: Can Y be used instead of X as a complement for Z (e.g. X and Y are butter and margarine and Z is bread)? If the answer is yes then BB King's function will do the job. If not then ramzan's answer it the one you are looking for (but I can't think of a good practical example of this case).

Answer (score 2):

I will leave the clarity of the question aside.

1) If what is meant by perfect substitutes/complements do not imply that these products are necessarily relevant for the preferences of an agent, then the answer is positive, with the utility function $U(x,y,z)$ being defined as 
$$
U(x,y,z)=0 \text{ for all } x,y, \text{ and }z.
$$
2) If it is implicitly understood that increasing $x$ and $z$ together would yield a higher utility and one for one transfer between $x$ and $y$ consumption yields the same utility for the agent, then the answer is negative. The reasoning can be seen as follows.
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbf{U(1,2,0)}&=&U(0,2,0) \text{ by perfect complementarity}\\
&<&U(1,2,1) \text{ since $x$ and $z$ consumption together is good}\\
&=&U(0,3,1) \text{ since $x$ and $y$ are perfect substitutes}\\
&=&U(0,3,0) \text{ due to perfect complementarity between $x$ and $z$}\\
&=&\mathbf{U(1,2,0)} \text{ since $x$ and $y$ are perfect substitutes}\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$
leading to a contradiction. A general proof can be written when the assumptions are relaxed, but I believe this is sufficiently clarifying.

Comment: Ah! So that's what the nuance behind the question's conditions. This is very good.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just asking for a utility function, then as BB King has noted, $U(x,y,z) = \min\left\{x+y, z\right\}$ works for perfect complements. If you are working with just complements in general, then you can put a weight on the goods to show their complementariness.

$$U(x,y,z) = \min \left\{\alpha(x + y), (1-\alpha)z \right\}$$

Remember though that the price of x and y may determine whether you actually buy x or y. If $p_x > p_y$, then the consumer will not purchase any of good $x$, and similarly for $p_y > p_x$.